# How do I correctly setup the multipart formdata with libcurl (in C++) to upload a binary file

Tags: c++, file-upload, multipartform-data, libcurl

To provide a little background.  I am not very experienced with Ethernet communications so I apologize in advance for that.  I'm working on a project where I need to figure out how to upload a binary file.

I'm trying to upload a large binary file (~34MB) to an embedded device. I have a python code snippet that works but I'm trying to implement the same capability in a different application using C++.  Using WireShark, I've captured the header from the python program that works as well as the header that I end up with in my C++ code which doesn't work as needed.

**Success Uploading with Python**

Here is the python code that works:

```
response = session.post('http://10.42.42.1:81/__FileUpload',
         files={"upfile": open(filename, 'rb')},
         stream=False)
```

Here is the header information extracted from the message which initiates the **successful** file upload:

```
POST /__FileUpload HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.42.42.1:81
Content-Length: 34112690
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.13 Windows/10
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=6a659e345a35419e99b66546c1bd9d4e

--6a659e345a35419e99b66546c1bd9d4e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="TestFile.bin"
```

**No Success with C++ Code**

Here is the essence of the code that I'm using to upload the file in C++:

```
curl_mime *multipart;
curl_mimepart *part;

// Specify the target URL
std::string str(comms.BaseURL() + kFileUploadEndpoint);
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, str.c_str());

multipart = curl_mime_init(pCurl);
part = curl_mime_addpart(multipart);
curl_mime_name(part, "upfile");
curl_mime_data(part, ("filename=\"" + FileName + "\"").c_str(), CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
part = curl_mime_addpart(multipart);
curl_mime_data_cb(part, fileSize, ReadCallback, SeekCallback, NULL, pFile);
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, multipart);
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90L);
res = curl_easy_perform(pCurl);
...
```

Here is the header information from running the C++ code:

```
--------------------------4977715f070a13da
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"

filename="TestFile.bin"
--------------------------4977715f070a13da
Content-Disposition: form-data
```

I realized that the header above does not contain the URL endpoint and such and noticed that apparently the message was split into two pieces.  Here is the header content from the message sent before the message above.

```
POST /__FileUpload HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.42.42.1:81
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 31546130
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------4977715f070a13da
Expect: 100-continue
```

I can check the status from the embedded device during the upload and the one thing that I notice in particular is that when the upload is successful with python then the embedded device reports the filename being uploaded in the status content reply.  However, when I run the C++ code the filename is blank when I check the status.  Therefore the embedded device is obviously not able to extract the filename from the C++ message.

**What the Embedded Device is Looking For**

While I don't have access to the source code of the device I did get the following information from someone who does.  He indicated that this is what the embedded device is looking for.  It didn't help me to figure out how to get things working but it might help someone else more knowledgeable in this area.

```
<FORM METHOD=POST name="install" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="HiddenFrame" action="/__FileUpload" onsubmit="InstallAction(); return true;">
    File to upload: <INPUT TYPE=FILE NAME="upfile" size=50><p>
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Submit" >
    </FORM>
```

I would prefer using the libcurl 'curl_mime_...' methods to setup the file upload only because that approach is recommended over using the older HTTP post methods.  However, I'm perfectly okay with using the older HTTP post methods if that is easier to do.  I just want to get it working.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding the solution.
It is posted here for anyone who could use it:

```
curl_mime *multipart;
curl_mimepart *part;

multipart = curl_mime_init(pCurl);
part = curl_mime_addpart(multipart);
curl_mime_name(part, "upfile");
curl_mime_filename(part, FileName.c_str());
curl_mime_data_cb(part, lSize, ReadCallback, SeekCallback, NULL, pFile);
part = curl_mime_addpart(multipart);

curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, multipart);

// Now send the message
res = curl_easy_perform(pCurl);

// Free the post data
curl_mime_free(multipart);
...
```

Comment: What is the extra part = curl_mime_addpart(multipart); after curl_mime_data_cb(part, lSize, ReadCallback, SeekCallback, NULL, pFile); ?

Answer (score 0):

> curl_mime_data(part, ("filename=\"" + FileName + "\"").c_str(), CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

I presume this wants to set the mime part's file name, and then you should rather use [curl_mime_filename](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_filename.html), because the file name is not data. Each part has a name and data, but also meta-data such as file name. Setting the file name only of course then requires that you set the data separately.

If you rather want to set the data *as well* as the file name, then instead do it with [curl_mime_filedata](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_filedata.html).

Also, take a look at the official libcurl example [postit2.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html).